# ActionResult - Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I bored, writing **same** code for service and ui. Then i tried to write a converter for simple actions. This converter, converting *Service Results* to *MVC result*, seems like good solution for me but anyway i think this gonna opposite MVC pattern.

So here, I need help, what you think about algorithm - is this good or not?

Thanks

ServiceResult - Base:

```
public abstract class ServiceResult
{
    public static NoPermissionResult Permission()
    {
        return new NoPermissionResult();
    }

    public static SuccessResult Success()
    {
        return new SuccessResult();
    }

    public static SuccessResult<T> Success<T>(T result)
    {
        return new SuccessResult<T>(result);
    }

    protected ServiceResult(ServiceResultType serviceResultType)
    {
        _resultType = serviceResultType;
    }

    private readonly ServiceResultType _resultType;
    public ServiceResultType ResultType
    {
        get { return _resultType; }
    }
}
public class SuccessResult<T> : ServiceResult
{
    public SuccessResult(T result)
        : base(ServiceResultType.Success)
    {
        _result = result;
    }

    private readonly T _result;
    public T Result
    {
        get { return _result; }
    }
}
public class SuccessResult : SuccessResult<object>
{
    public SuccessResult() : this(null) { }
    public SuccessResult(object o) : base(o) { }
}
```

Service - eg. ForumService:

```
public ServiceResult Delete(IVUser user, int id)
{
    Forum forum = Repository.GetDelete(id);
    if (!Permission.CanDelete(user, forum))
    {
        return ServiceResult.Permission();
    }
    Repository.Delete(forum);
    return ServiceResult.Success();
}
```

Controller:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult GetResult(ServiceResult result)
    {
        switch (result.ResultType)
        {
            case ServiceResultType.Success:
                var successResult = (SuccessResult)result;
                return View(successResult.Result);
                break;
            case ServiceResultType.NoPermission:
                return View("Error");
                break;
            default:
                return View();
                break;
        }
    }
}

[HandleError]
public class ForumsController : BaseController
{
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Transaction]
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        ServiceResult result = ForumService.Delete(WebUser.Current, id);

        /* Custom result */
        if (result.ResultType == ServiceResultType.Success)
        {
            TempData[ControllerEnums.GlobalViewDataProperty.PageMessage.ToString()] = "The forum was successfully deleted.";
            return this.RedirectToAction(ec => Index());
        }
        /* Custom result */

        /* Execute Permission result etc. */
        TempData[ControllerEnums.GlobalViewDataProperty.PageMessage.ToString()] = "A problem was encountered preventing the forum from being deleted. " +
            "Another item likely depends on this forum.";


        return GetResult(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the company that I am working in we use the same algorithm. We consider it to be an MVVM not MVC. So I think that this algorithm is good.

I'm just wondering, how do you handle redirections? Do you have a redirection service result type, or you decide to redirect or to not redirect in the controller?

Comment: IMO, Only for basic things, (e.g. exception thrown, no such record). Other things should be taken care in action method.